# create migration for model that in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have a 'question' model in Subdirectory Exceed::Question.

now I want to add migration for Question model, so I run

`rails g migration AddImageToExceedQuestions`

after that when I run `rake db:migrate

Its show error -

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'bs_development.questions' doesn't exist: ALTER TABLE `questions`
```

In my database question model save as **exceed_question**.

I also try `rails g migration AddImageToQuestions` and `rails g migration AddImageToExceed::Questions` but get same error.

How I can create migration for model that in subdirectory.

Comment: Can you explain `Subdirectory Exceed::Question.`? A subdirectory is a path in file system, `Exceed::Question.` looks like a module hierarchy. (Maybe this mixture of pathes and modules is already your problem.)

Comment: when I created question model, I run 'rails g model Exceed::Question' so my question model path is **app/models/exceed/question.rb**

Comment: You have to manually edit the migration file, and set the table name correctly

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I ran `rails g model Exceed::Question` and `rails g migration AddImageToExceedQuestions`. Both migrations run fine. Have you edited the migration file?

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord migrations are not actually tied to model classes. They simply modify the schema and database tables but do not care about if your models actually exist at all.

The rails generators are smart enough to recognize some forms such as `rails g migration AddNameToFooBar name:string` which would generate:

```
class AddNameToFooBar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :foo_bars, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Rails will recognize that the part after to is a table name and snake case it. And then pluralize the last word if it is singular.

`rails g migration add_name_to_foo_bar name:string` creates an identical migration. The same with `rails g migration add_name_to_foo_bars name:string` except for the file & class name of the migration.

You can fix your issue by opening up the migration file and ensuring that it has the correct table

```
class AddImageToExceedQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :exceed_questions, :image, :string # or binary
  end
end
```

Note that your table should be named `exceed_questions`, tables in rails use the plural form of the table name.

Comment: "Namespaced" models simply use an underscore in the table name and rails will look for `ExceedQuestion` before looking for `Exceed::Question` when linking the table name to a class (such as when loading a relation). Thats unless you use the plural form of the first word `users_cats` will look for `Users::Cats`.